# Acceso a Nugget log4net

Tags: c#

trato de hacer que el Nugget log4net version 1.2.13.0
y me sale esto:

> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Se produjo una
>   excepción en el destino de la invocación.
>
> (C:\AplicacionesWeb\MasterDetail\web.config line 55) --->
>   System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Se produjo una excepción
>   en el destino de la invocación. --->
>   System.TypeInitializationException: Se produjo una excepción en el
>   inicializador de tipo de 'Dimex.Security.DxPermissionProvider'. --->
>   System.IO.FileLoadException: No se puede cargar el archivo o
>   ensamblado 'log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a' ni una de sus dependencias.

es la dll del log4net al parecer

Pero el problema es que si lo actualizo a 2.0.8.0 pues pierdo la mayoria de la cofig. como instalarlo sin perder nada? o que recomiendan que podria mejorar

Comment: ¿Viste si los requisitos del log4net 1.2.13.0 permiten usarlo bajo la versión de .Net Framework que este usando?

Comment: Si revise la version de framework de el proyecto y estan en la version de compatibilidad de ambos

Comment: Si en la solucion tienes varios proyectos debes validar que todos utilicen la misma version del componente log4net, si algunos proyectos pones una version y en otros uan diferente al compilar tendras ese mensaje. Al iniciar el proyecto principal ira pisando las dependencias y dejara una que no todos utilizan